# Argument "options" is not a valid SetOptions error on Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to copy my real time database contents to firestore. But I'm getting this error when I use the set function.

```
exports.copyPosts = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var i = 0;
    var username;
    db.ref("feeds").child("all").limitToLast(2000).once("value", function (postSnap) {
        console.log(postSnap.numChildren());
        postSnap.forEach(function(topic){
                    i = i + 1;
                    console.log(topic.key);
                    firestore.collection("topics").doc("all").collection(i+"").set({
                        caption: topic.child("caption").val(),
                        time: topic.child("time").val(),
                        username: topic.child("username").val(),
                        category: topic.child("category").val(),
                        pic: topic.child("pic").val()

                    },function(error) {
                      if (error) {
                        alert("Data could not be saved." + error);
                      } else {
                        alert("Data saved successfully.");
                    }
                    });

                if(postSnap.numChildren()==i){
                    res.contentType('application/json');
                    res.status(200).send("Success");
                }
            });
        });

});
```

Error Log

> Error: Argument "options" is not a valid SetOptions. Input is not an
>   object.
>       at exports.(anonymous function) (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:86:15)
>       at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as isOptionalSetOptions] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/validate.js:91:35)
>       at WriteBatch.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/write-batch.js:268:14)
>       at DocumentReference.set (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/src/reference.js:425:8)
>       at /user_code/index.js:2172:47
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/api/DataSnapshot.js:126:20
>       at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/util/SortedMap.js:170:13)
>       at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/util/SortedMap.js:169:27)
>       at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/util/SortedMap.js:169:27)
>       at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/util/SortedMap.js:169:27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The API documentation for the set() method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/DocumentReference#set) states that it takes two arguments:

- data: A map of the fields and values for the document.
- options: (Optional) An object to configure the set behavior.

You're passing it two arguments, an object, and a function.  It appears that you expect the function to be called in the event of an error, but that's not how the documentation is saying that it works.  The error you're getting the API seeing that you're not passing a valid options object at the optional second parameter.

If you're interested in the result of the set() operation, pay attention to the promise that it returns.  The convention is that a promise will be rejected in the case of an error.  If you're going to be writing Cloud Functions code, you definitely need to be familiar with how promises work.

Comment: When I remove the error function. It works. But the set method doesnt work. I mean it returns success and loop completely work. But no data in firestore database. And I dont even get any logs..

Comment: I just used promises and added  the added the result code inside then function and it worked. Thank you so much..